# Import DB from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm importing a cell text from a Google Spreadsheet and inserting into a post on WordPress using the follow code. But I have more than 300 values to get. So, I was wondering if that is any easier way to import it without coping the long sheet URL over the 300 times.
It also could be in `php`, so I would insert in my page.php file, but I have no idea how to do it.

```js
jQuery.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=c3&output=csv").done(function(txt1){
               jQuery("#text1").html(txt1);
});

jQuery.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=c4&output=csv").done(function(txt2){
               jQuery("#text2").html(txt2);
});

jQuery.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=c5&output=csv").done(function(txt3){
               jQuery("#text3").html(txt3);
});
```

```html
<div id='text1'></div>
<div id='text2'></div>
<div id='text3'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, why are you making 300 calls to a spreadsheet?  Just do one call and get the cells you care about.  There is a parameter in the URL `single`, set it to false, and then pass in the range of cells you want.

But since I don't know what cells those are, I guess you could do:

```
function getCell(cell, id) {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=" 
               + cell + "&output=csv";
    jQuery.ajax(url).done(function(t){
           $(id).html(t);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    var cell = 'c' + (i+3);      //first iteration: "c3"
    var dest = '#text' + (i+1);  //first iteration: "#text1"
    getCell(cell, dest);
}
```